# In Magento, make same customer use different quotes on different browsers

Tags: php, magento, session

Unfortunately, due to circumstances beyond my control, I need to make the following configuration work:

Alice logs in as a Customer with username foo.

Then Bob logs in as the same Customer (foo) on a different browser.

Alice and Bob each have separate shopping carts. When Alice adds something to the cart in her browser, Bob's cart is not affected.

In Magento's default configuration, Alice and Bob share one cart stored on the server, and thus the cart is synchronized between them. Is there any way I can force Magento's sessions to work the way I need them to?

> **EDIT:**
>   Thanks for the replies! After looking into some of the hints in Alan's
>   answer, I guess the crux of my question is whether quotes can be made
>   to apply to sessions rather than to users.
>
> Can I hook onto some login event and do something like:
>
> ```
> Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuoteId(null);
> ```
>
> And still keep the cart of the user logged in on the other browser?

Comment: I don't know Magento in depth but I wouldn't be surprised if it weren't possible for architectural reasons. What is your use case for this? Maybe someone can suggest a workaround with somehow connected accounts or something

Comment: @user2347857, did you end up making any progress regarding this?

Comment: You could make this work but I'm having difficulty understanding the end result here. This question is fairly old but in Magento 2 the request here is very close to Magento's B2B functionality.

Answer (score 2):

That is a very odd use case, but one that doesn't seem to be related to "sessions" as much as limitations of the cart.  Seems like new functionality you would need to create if you want to support multiple carts per user. Functionality which would need to include UI changes and other changes throughout the system, so as to not really confuse users who might legitimately log into the site in different browsers (perhaps on different devices) and want to see their SAME shopping cart.

So I would say if you you need to think about this on a deeper level than just changing cart behavior, and think of it more as modifying base application functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen a turn-key extension or cookbook solution that would allow you to do this.   You might want to try asking this question over on the [StackExchange Magento site](http://magento.stackexchange.com) — non programming questions are more welcome over there.

If I was going to build/program this feature, my general approach would be

1. Find an event that fires after a customer logs in, and then setup an observer for this event
2. In the observer, find the last unconverted "cart" for the user that just logged in using the `sales/quote` object (i.e. the `sales_flat_quote` table).
3. Then, still in the observer, I'd use the `setQuoteId` method of the cart session to make this old quote the current quote

The above is a naive approach to the problem — I'm not sure if Magento [persistant cart](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/persistent-shopping-cart-customer-segmentation-just-getting-better/) feature would play nice with the above, but the fastest way to find out would be to implement something, test, and iterate.

This is not a simple solution, unless this functionality is a live or die business requirement, I'd skip the feature.

Comment: I totally misread the question — the above describes how to implement Magento existing behavior